# Google App Engine Standard - ImportError - Exception Value: cannot import name exceptions

Tags: django, google-app-engine, django-rest-framework

I am trying to deploy a **Django 1.11.18** project to **google app engine standard** and I am getting following error.

I am uploading all the required library along with my project.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: ImportError at /swagger-docs/
    cannot import name exceptions
    Request Method: GET
    Request URL: https://xyz.appspot.com/swagger-docs/
    Django Version: 1.11.18
    Exception Type: ImportError
    **Exception Value: 
    cannot import name exceptions**
    Exception Location: /lib/coreapi/utils.py in <module>, line 1
    Python Executable: /base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27g/7e468a4e2dbc991a/python27/python27_dist/python
    Python Version: 2.7.12

Comment: Please edit your question and place the (full) traceback in there, not in comments - you can then format it so it's readable. Thanks.

Comment: @DanCornilescu.. Thanks Dan,.. I apologize for the non-readability,.. I did what you suggested but stackoverflow wont let me submit my questions,.. saying too much code :-) So did the comments hack,.. Please suggest if there is a workaround.

Comment: Didn't know the question itself also has a limit. Anyways, you need to select just the relevant code snippets. Are you sure you're using the `edit` button under your post? Check https://stackoverflow.com/tour and https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Comment: you can also upload all your code on Github and share it here

Answer (score 0):

After few trail and errors, I figure the issue is with Google App Engine Standard environment. It looks like I needed to add setuptools to lib to get around this issue.

pip install setuptools -t ./lib

Let me know if there is a better solution.

Comment: did you setup "app.yaml" and "requirements.txt" correctly? Check GCP quickstart with Django and Python: https://cloud.google.com/python/django/appengine